# What do you call a surface of a chopped log?

Tags: word-request

Imagine you are chopping the log with an axe. You chopped it into parts, and every part has some outer surface, been previously the outer part of the log [bark], and newer surfaces, been previously the inner part of the log, now split from each other, and splintered.

How do you call the latter? One of this inner surfaces, more light on the picture.[image]

A ***Chip*** is defined by [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chip) as

> a small usually thin and flat piece (as of wood or stone) cut, struck, or flaked off
> Blockquote

while the inner surface seems to be pretty big compared to that.

***Crack*** and ***split*** seem not to be done completely, as if log is not broken yet.

***Splinter*** seems to be something like shard, and also very small.

And the ***cleavage*** is ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cleavage))

> a fragment (as of a diamond) obtained by splitting

but also

> the action of cleaving or splitting : the state of being cleft

which I am not sure what to think about.

Comment: Hello Tony.  Does this surface have a special name in your language?  How would you use your word in a sentence?

Comment: If I really had to refer to it, I might call it the *exposed face* or simply *the exposed surface* of the cut log.

Comment: @James K
In my language it would be something like 'split', meaning the side/place (small or not), where the material was split. It also can be applied to such surface.

This was my initial intention, but in English 'split' seems to mean just 'crack'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm telling someone how best to put a piece of wood on a fire, I'll tell them to face a **split side** towards the fire, as opposed to the **bark side**.

Comment: Yes. Learners somehow get the impression that every conceivable concept has an English word just waiting for it.